# Strange sounds heard worldwide...any SSD comments?

Tags: strange, sounds, recording

http://www.datelinezero.com/2012/01/17/strange-sounds-heard-worldwide/

apparently this is a video compilation that has been floating around the net recently.  Anyone out there get a decent recording? 
Care to comment on these?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hoax:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZ2ZcmMxehk

Listen to 0:45 and 13:34 -- same bird noises, same screeching, same 'alien' noise...

Answer (score 1):

Is this the first hoax to employ social media like facebook? Not bad, although it seems that the commenters on the youtube video are picking up on (as well as the birds) the "Hollywood-ness" of the groaning metal sound. If it was me, i would have gone with a less easily recognisable sound.

Can creating an Unidentified Aural Object be the next Sound Design Challenge?

Comment: but still its kinda creepy, at least for me:)